# Azure CDN Blob Storage Manual Compression

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-cdn

We have files that are over 1mb and excluded from the automatic compression through Azure Verizon CDN.

To accommodate we manually compress the files before uploading to the Azure Blob backbone. We upload both an compressed and uncompressed version of the file.

[image: uploaded files]

We have also configured Azure CDN to handle json file :

[image: mime config]

Now if i curl the blob or cdn with the appropriate headers, I do not get compressed content.

[image]

So what is the standard approach to doing this with Azure? Am I missing a setting or header?

Is content swapping not doable based on the Accept-Encoding header?

Do I need to drop the .gz extension and always serve the json zipped?

Any insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit for clarity:**

The recommended solution here is to gzip and upload your asset to blog storage without the .gz extension and make sure it returns the "Content-Encoding:gzip" header.

After that, just request that asset through the CDN endpoint. If your request contains an *Accept-Encoding:gzip* header, the CDN will return the compressed asset. If your request does not contain the *Accept-Encoding* header, the CDN will uncompress the file on the fly and serve the client the uncompressed version of the asset.

**Original Answer:**

Hey, I'm from the Azure CDN team.

First, are you using a Verizon or Akamai profile?

Verizon has a limit of 1MB for edge compression while Akamai does not. Also, this limit is just for CDN edge compression, so if your origin responds with the correct compressed file, the CDN should still serve it to the client.

Blob storage doesn't automatically do content swapping as far as I'm aware.

Note that if an uncompressed version of the file was already cached on the CDN edge, it will continue to serve that file until it expires. You can reset this by using the 'purge' function.

We also have a troubleshooting document here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-troubleshoot-compression

I'd be happy to help you troubleshoot further, if the above doesn't help.
Just send me your origin and cdn endpoint URLs privately at rli@microsoft.com.

Comment: We are using Verizon, the source server is Azure blob storage. It does not respond with compressed content. I have purged, and loaded the CDN endpoint, as well as tried using query strings to bust the cache ( since the CDN is configured to cache every unique url) I've been through the troubleshooting guide to no avail. What is really needed is a guide on how to setup manual compression for an Azure CDN backed by blob storage. It does not seem to exist anywhere, but given the 1mb limit, it would seem to be a common requirement. An email is on the way. Thanks!

Comment: I sent you an email, but sharing here as well. In this case with Verizon, you want to use the url of the asset which you already compressed to serve your content. The CDN can serve it to the user compressed, or de-compress it on the fly, depending on the Accept-Encoding header in the request.

Comment: Just responded. One thing that was not clear to me was that the file will decompress from the cdn based on the Accept-Encoding header. That simplifies matters somewhat, but it would still be nice if it could check for the .gz